# what is the use of string replace method in ruby?

Tags: ruby, string, replace

i read `string` methods in `ruby`. i understood `replace` will replace the `string` with the `argument` passed to it. But the same thing we can do with a short and sweet `=` oparator also. what is the point of using `replace` method? its just a `personnel` `choice` or it's different from an `=` operator?

```
    > a = "hell­o world­"
   => "hello world"
   > a = "123"­
   => "123"
   > a.replace(­"345")
   => "345"
```

Answer (score 2):

This line of code changes the variable `a` to point to a new string:

```
a = "new string"
```

This line of code actually changes the string object that `a` (and possibly other variables) are pointing to:

```
a.replace "new string"
```

Comment: I agree with @David

@John if you look at the source code in C (http://ruby-doc.org/core-1.9.3/String.html#method-i-replace) you will see that `a` in your case is not reinitializing, think of `replace` as change this variable in place.

Answer (score 2):

**Using `=`**

```
str = "cat in the hat"
str.object_id
  #=> 70331872197480 

def a(str)
  str = "hat on the cat"
  puts "in method str=#{str}, str.object_id=#{str.object_id}"
end

a(str)
in method str=hat on the cat, str.object_id=70331873031040

str
  #=> "cat in the hat" 
str.object_id
  #=> 70331872197480
```

The values of `str` outside the method and `str` inside the method are different objects.

**Using [String#replace](http://ruby-doc.org/core-2.3.0/String.html#method-i-replace)**

```
str = "cat in the hat"
str.object_id
  #=> 70331872931060 

def b(str)
  str.replace("hat on the cat")
  puts "in method str=#{str}, str.object_id=#{str.object_id}"
end

b(str)
in method str=hat on the cat, str.object_id=70331872931060

str
  #=> "hat on the cat" 
str.object_id
  #=> 70331872931060
```

The values of `str` outside the method and `str` inside the method are the same object.

Comment: Probably worth mentioning something about `object_id` being a good way to find out if an object has changed or not.

Answer (score 1):

The use case is really just, to achieve something much like pass-by-reference in other languages, where a variable's value can be changed directly. So you could pass a String to a method and that method may entirely change the string to something else.

```
def bar(bazzer)
  bazzer.replace("reference")
end

bar(baz)

=> It's reference because local assignment is above the food chain , but it's clearly pass-by-reference
```

This makes sense.